# Not able to see all the members when getting list of IAM users for a bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am trying to get list of all the IAM users having access to a particular bucket with the below command:

```
gsutil iam get gs://<bucket_name>
```

I am getting output with only legacy roles:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "members": [
        "projectEditor:PROJECT_ID",
        "projectOwner:PROJECT_ID"
      ],
      "role": "roles/storage.legacyBucketOwner"
    },
    {
      "members": [
        "projectViewer:PROJECT_ID"
      ],
      "role": "roles/storage.legacyBucketReader"
    },
    {
      "members": [
        "projectEditor:PROJECT_ID",
        "projectOwner:PROJECT_ID"
      ],
      "role": "roles/storage.legacyObjectOwner"
    },
    {
      "members": [
        "projectViewer:PROJECT_ID"
      ],
      "role": "roles/storage.legacyObjectReader"
    }
  ],
  "etag": "CAE="
}
```

However, I do have additional users and service accounts that have access to this bucket. How do I get list of all the users and service accounts having access to the bucket?

P.S: All the permissions over the bucket to different users are provided through IAM only.

Comment: IAM permissions can be granted at the resource (cloud storage bucket/object) and at the project. You must list the IAM bindings for both.

Comment: You can use IAM Analyser for that: https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/analyzing-iam-policy

Comment: Policy analyzer tool really helped to get the required information. Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere

Answer (score 0):

Looks like policy analyzer tool provides the required information.
https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/analyzing-iam-policy

Code sample: https://github.com/googleapis/python-asset/blob/dd28cb0dd897d9386c45a4ec4d4ce8090d986052/samples/snippets/quickstart_analyzeiampolicy.py

However, the question is why

> gsutil iam get gs://BUCKET

is not returning all the roles and members that have access to bucket? Is there any additional flag or configuration that needs to be passed to the above command.